# Is it possible to make point vector reycast in pcl?

Tags: c++, raycasting, point-cloud-library

I have a 3d points world. I have point in it `a [x,y,z]` and direction  (azimuthal angle `θ`, and polar angle ) I want to get point `b [x2,y2,z2]` where my ray (sent from my point `a` into direction) would stop. (only from one point and only for one direction). How to do such thing in pcl, is it possible (I see a [ray caster class](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/structpcl_1_1gpu_1_1_ray_caster.html#ad7b64edce595a883b446cfb2006f7121) but it seems to work on whole world not point to point)?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `OctreePointCloudSearch` class might help you a little bit more. Have a quick look at the `OctreePointCloudSearch::getIntersectedVoxelIndices` method: once your point cloud is organized in an octree, it allows you to specify the origin and a direction for the ray to be used for raycasting. In your case, the origin would be the point **a** and the direction would be obtained from the azimuthal and polar angles ([see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system))

The function returns the indices to the point within the intersected voxels.

If you google for that class name you can easily find a good number of working examples ([this example](http://rovis.unitbv.ro/rovis/trunk/src/tracking/CPointCloudTracker.cpp) casts a ray from each point of the cloud toward the camera and checks for occlusions).